# How to fix Newtonsoft.Json assembly loading error?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, json.net, nuget, umbraco

I'm attempting to load a pre-existing Umbraco CMS site into a Visual Studio project and am caught up in a bit of DLL hell.

Here is the error message I get when attempting to compile the site:

```
Could not load types from assembly Umbraco.Core, Version=1.0.5462.37503, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, errors:
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

I've attempted to re-install Newtonsoft from NuGet, re-install Umbraco from NuGet, delete all DLLs and re-install, removed the Newtonsoft dependentAssembly, every possible solution I've been able to find and this error continues to come up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bit of a misunderstanding on my part from following the Umbraco videos. I was attempting to set up a new Visual Studio project, import all the DLLs needed, and then move the site content into the project.

All I really needed to do was create a blank project, then move the site content, with all of its DLLs, into the project. This let me immediately start editing the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the binding redirect isn't set up correctly in the web.config file. Try running this in the nuget package manager console:

```
PM> Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was to install an earlier version of the package and then upgrade.